# Elementos comunes en tres pares de arreglos Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo un archivo con 12 columnas, que corresponde a 3 grupos de 4 datos, como por ejemplo `A1-B1-C1-D1-A2-B2-C2-D2-A3-B3-C3-D3`. Quiero buscar cuándo sea

```
A1[i]=A2[j]=A3[k]
```

y al mismo tiempo

```
B1[i]=B2[j]=B3[k]
```

Cuándo eso ocurra, quiero guardar `C1[i], D1[i], C2[j], D2[j], C3[k], D3[k]`. El problema es que son muchos datos (~600 mil) y se demora mucho si no lo hago de una forma más eficiente que con `for` e `if`.

Comment: Hola María, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. ¿Podrías poner el código que has utilizado hasta ahora? Así podremos ver si es un problema con el algoritmo o que es difícil sacar más rendimiento con Python. ¿Cuánto tiempo se te demora exactamente?

Comment: Hola, María. A pesar de que entiendo el problema que planteas, al tener un problema de rendimiento se hace difícil mejorarlo si no vemos qué código has usado. Así mismo, interesaría saber si tienes alguna información relativa a los datos de entrada, como que estén ordenados, si se repiten con alguna frecuencia, si puede coincidir más de tres líneas y, sobre todo, si caben en memoria. Así, sin más, es un problema típico de complejidad O(n^2 log n) que se simplifica enormemente si estuvieran los datos previamente ordenados o si tuvieran una tabla hash ó índice.

Comment: También sería interesante saber si puedes utilizar/instalar otras librerías como numpy que podrían simplificar tu problema.